# Browserify - Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'undefined'

Tags: npm, browserify, commonjs

In my final bundle.js file which includes all js modules, I'm getting the following error

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'undefined'
at s (bundle.js:1)
at bundle.js:1
at Object.33.../Utility (bundle.js:12704)
at s (bundle.js:1)
at bundle.js:1
at Object.11../CalculationsProcessor (bundle.js:10397)
at s (bundle.js:1)
at bundle.js:1
at Object.7../src/CalculationsPage (bundle.js:10166)
at s (bundle.js:1)
```

Though, all those modules (i.e. ../Utility, ./CalculationsProcessor, ./src/CalculationsPage) already exists in the bundle.js, encapsulated in separate anonymous function and are attached to different keys.

Have no clue what to do, please help!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem with browserify.